# mysql in terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal

When I try to connect to mysql via terminal, I get this error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

What might be causing this? I've tried changing permissions on my tmp directory but that didn't work. The mysql.sock file also doesn't exist.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have MySQL Server configured with non-default settings - specifically, disabled socket connections or altered socket file. You can try connecting via another socket (check my.cnf config file for specific socket file name):

```
mysql -u username -pPassword --socket=/your/path/to/socket/file
```

or you can also try connecting through TCP:

```
mysql -u username -pPassword -h your_hostname_or_ip -P 3306
```

3306 is default TCP port for MySQL but that also may vary depending on your settings in my.cnf.

BTW, your question might be better fit for [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/)